# Pocket Sphinx on Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

What are the steps required to use PocketSphinx on Android?

I have found various hints around the web that it is possible, but not real answers and hence I ask my question here.

Comment: You would be far better served asking your question on a Sphinx-related forum: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/communicate/

Comment: I am unable to understand how to use Pocket Sphinx...do I just download it from `github` (which I have no experience in using) and import that project into android studio? I'm really confused, and I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://swathiep.blogspot.com/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html) is the most comprehensive resource I've found to date. I still have some compilation errors, though. The blog gives you a tutorial on how to build the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo app, which was developed (and discontinued) on [GitHub](https://github.com/cjac/cmusphinx/tree/trunk/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo).

Personally, I'm having similar compilation errors to the Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505633/problems-trying-to-build-pocketsphinx-for-android-using-ndk), but my rep is too low to ask for clarification on the answer.

Comment: @ozmank I have a windows OS and can't make i have errors in my installation.

Comment: @mocca use linux to compile the libs

Answer (score 2):

The latest and most relevant official tutorial is available on CMUSphinx website

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Most of other tutorials are unforutnately outdated but they are posted on external websites so we have no control over them.

Comment: I am unable to understand how to use CMUSphinx...do I just download it from `github` (which I have no experience in using) and import that project into android studio? I'm really confused, and I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!