# Problems trying to build PocketSphinxAndroidDemo using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, swig, android-ndk-r5, cmusphinx

I am trying to compile PocketSphinxAndroidDemo, which provides an example implementation of the CMU pocketsphinx speech recognizer on Android. I first received an error similar to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505633/problems-trying-to-build-pocketsphinx-for-android-using-ndk). After executing ndk-build, I got this error:

```
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : pocketsphinx_jni <= pocketsphinx_wrap.c
/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:761:28: error: sphinxbase/err.h: No such file or directory
/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Java_edu_cmu_pocketsphinx_pocketsphinxJNI_Decoder_1processRaw_1_1SWIG_10':
/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:1441: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o] Error 1
```

I tried the recommendation of rebuilding the `sphinxbase` and `pocketsphinx` libraries and rebuilding with `ndk-build -B`, but that didn't work. I then modified the jni/pocketsphinx.i swig file to change the include for err.h:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>
//#include <sphinxbase/err.h>
#include <err.h>
```

Did anyone that tried to compile PocketSphinxAndroidDemo ever encounter this problem? My edit seemed to allow me to get further in my compilation, but now I'm getting assembly-related errors:

```
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : pocketsphinx_jni <= pocketsphinx_wrap.c
/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Java_edu_cmu_pocketsphinx_pocketsphinxJNI_Decoder_1processRaw_1_1SWIG_10':
/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:1442: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
Compile thumb  : sphinxfeat <= cmn.c
/tmp/cceyE035.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cceyE035.s:655: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r1,r2,r0,r4'
/tmp/cceyE035.s:657: Error: unshifted register required -- `orr r1,r1,r2,lsl#20'
/tmp/cceyE035.s:932: Error: selected processor does not support `smull r1,r2,r0,r4'
/tmp/cceyE035.s:934: Error: unshifted register required -- `orr r1,r1,r2,lsl#20'
make: *** [/home/nick/workspace/android/PocketSphinxDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/sphinxfeat/cmn.o] Error 1
```

Again, does anyone know how to resolve this problem? I haven't seen any other developers complaining of this problem, so I'm hesitant to go further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I managed to get my code to compile, using my solution below; however, I'm not convinced that this is necessary, because I haven't read about anyone else needing to do the same thing. So, please feel free to propose your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, some of the sources still needed to be marked for ARM compilation. I modified the following section of Android.mk to set cmn.c and lda.c to compile with ARM.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include/android $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID_NDK

LOCAL_PATH := $(SPHINX_PATH)/sphinxbase/src/libsphinxbase/feat
LOCAL_MODULE := sphinxfeat

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    agc.c \
    cmn.c.arm \
    cmn_prior.c.arm \
    feat.c \
    lda.c.arm
```

I am still wondering if anyone else had to do this to get their code to compile successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Edit file jni/Android.mk

Change Line 162 :

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := sphinxutil sphinxfe sphinxfeat sphinxlm pocketsphinx
```

to :

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := pocketsphinx sphinxlm sphinxfeat sphinxfe sphinxutil
```