# Error building PocketSphinx Demo Project for Android with pocketsphinx_wrap.c

Tags: android, android-ndk-r5

I have downloaded these 3 projects:
PocketSphinxAndroidDemo
pocketsphinx
sphinxbase

i have updated C:\android-ndk-r5b\samples\PocketSphinxAndroidDemo\jni\Android.mk file
line 006: SPHINX_PATH := /home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples

But in the moment in that I try run ndk-build to create libpocketsphinx_jni.so file: /home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/ndk-build V=1 NDK_LOG=1, appear the following errors with the pocketsphinx_wrap.c specifically:

```
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:757:26: error: pocketsphinx.h: No such file or directory
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:758:28: error: sphinxbase/err.h: No such file or directory
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Hypothesis':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:777: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:779: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:781: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Config__SWIG_0':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:792: error: 'FALSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:792: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:792: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Config__SWIG_1':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:796: error: 'FALSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Config_getString':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:827: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Decoder__SWIG_0':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:836: error: 'FALSE' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'new_Decoder__SWIG_1':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:840: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Decoder_getConfig':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:844: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Decoder_getUttid':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:853: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Decoder_getHyp':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:866: error: 'int32' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:866: error: expected ';' before 'best_score'
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:867: error: 'best_score' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c: In function 'Java_edu_cmu_pocketsphinx_pocketsphinxJNI_Decoder_1processRaw_1_1SWIG_10':
/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:1435: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
make: *** [/home/eliana/android-ndk-r5b/samples/PocketSphinxAndroidDemo/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/pocketsphinx_jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.o] Error 1
```

I appreciate any help because it is very important for me to try PocketSphinx on Android.

Thanks,

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10124163/1318048

Answer (score 2):

try to change your floders names sphinxbase.X.X  and pocketsphinx.X.X to sphinxbase and pocketsphinx

hope that this will help

Answer (score 0):

i think you are giving a wrong path in the android.mk
if you download the project then you will find at the same path were pocketsphinxdemo exist you will find two folder "pocketsphinx" and  "sphinxbase"
this is the path where you need to specify in your android make file in your project

I hope that this will help 
amal :)